# Name fileOutputStream with Incremental Integer

Tags: java, file

I am attempting to read files from one folder and store then in another folder with the original file name and an increasing integer but i am not succeeding:

```
File f = new File(C:/FILES);
String listfiles[] = f.list();
for (int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    FileInputStream fstemp = new FileInputStream("C:/FILES/" + listfiles[i]);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/TEMPFILES/" +count + "_"+ listfiles[i]);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstemp));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    String strLine;
    ..................
    count++;
}
```

All my files are being moved to the temp folder with 0 integer. I need 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You variable `count` is set to `0` each time new loop iteration begins.

Just put its declaration on the previous line:

```
int count = 0; //
for (int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have `count` not be reinitialized at each turn of the loop to `0`...

You have essentially this:

```
for (<conditions>) {
  int count = 0; // whoops, set to 0 for every iteration!!

   // do stuff

   count++;
}
```

You want this:

```
int count = 0;
for (<conditions>) {

   // do stuff

   count++;
}
```

#### Extra Notes:

- I hope you are release those file-handles in finally block somewhere that we don't see.
- You could use `i` for `count`.
- The example you gave us is incomplete and doesn't work. Please give us a SSCCE. For instance, your `File f = new File(C:/FILES);` is obviously different in your actual code.
- If you want to copy files and this isn't homework, may I interest you in Apache Commons's `FileUtils` class or Guava's `Files` ?
- You might want to check that the files don't already exist, and maybe use a temporary folder and temporary file name generator.

#### Suggested Rewrite

*For Java 5 and 6. Java 7 would be nicer with try-with-resources.*

```
int i = 0;

for (final String f : new File("C:/FILES").list()) {
  final FileInputStream fstemp = null;
  FileOutputStream fos = null;

  try {
    fstemp = new FileInputStream(f);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/TEMPFILES/" + i + "_"+ f.getName()));

    // go on with your manual copy code... or use Guava's Files.copy(File, File):
    //   copy(f, new File("C:/TEMPFILES/" + i + "_"+ f.getName()))

    // more stuff here
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
     // catch here if you feel like, and do something about it
  } finally {
     // close streams if not null
  }
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Ah this is a very elaborate example I appreciate.

Comment: @Stanley: Glad you did. Sad Andremoniy was maybe just a few seconds faster though :)

Comment: +2 For a Comprehensive Answer. next time it will be you :)

Comment: @Stanley: nah that was fair. It's the law of the game :)